# Conditional merge on in pandas

Tags: pandas

My question in simple I am using pd.merge to merge two df .
Here's the line of code:

`pivoted = pd.merge(pivoted, concerned_data, on='A')`

and I want the on='B' whenever a row has column A value as null. Is there a possible way to do this?

Edit:

As an example if

```
 df1:   A | B |randomval
        1 | 1 |   ty
       Nan| 2 | asd
```

```
 df2:   A | B  |randomval2
        1 | Nan|   tyrte
        3 | 2  | asde
```

So if on='A' and the value is Nan is any of the df (for a single row) I want on='B' for that row only

Thank you!

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Isolate the lines where 'A' is null in another dataframe, merge on 'B' on this one, drop na rows in original and merge on 'A' on the remaining one with no null 'A'. Then concat

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler solution since there are three columns I can merge on but some rows can miss any of them.

Comment: For now, I have implemented @Mayeulsgc suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a third column in your `pandas.DataFrame` which incorporates this logic and merge on this one.

For example, create dummy data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1, None], "B" : [1, 2], "Val1" : ["a", "b"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1, 2], "B" : [None, 2], "Val2" : ["c", "d"]})
```

Create a column `c` which has this logic

```
df1["C"] = pd.concat([df1.loc[~df1.A.isna(), "A"], df1.loc[df1.A.isna(), "B"]],ignore_index=False)
df2["C"] = pd.concat([df2.loc[~df2.A.isna(), "A"], df2.loc[df2.A.isna(), "B"]],ignore_index=False)
```

Finally, merge on this common column and include only your value columns

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1[["Val1","C"]], df2[["Val2","C"]], on='C')

In [27]: df3
Out[27]:
  Val1    C Val2
0    a  1.0    c
1    b  2.0    d
```

Comment: Ok, but how would I know that which value I am comparing to in both? I mean can only merge on either A or on B, but that value has to be in both the df.

Comment: Well `C` is equivalent to `A` where `.isna()` is false, else it will be equivalent `B`, so those are the values you are merging on. Not sure what exactly you mean by the above... Maybe in your Question provide an example of the desired output based on the two `df`'s you provided, so I can see what's the issue with the above. I simply used that and implemented what I thought of the  logic *if on='A' and the value is Nan is any of the df (for a single row) I want on='B' for that row only*